# UITextView length issue

Tags: swift, uitextview

I've a `UITextView` with scroll enabled, I can change font and size of the text inside. So, How can I set a text limit? I've already tried to set max row and max number of character but it doesn't working because I need to set a size limit of the text, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you'd conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, specify your view controller as the `delegate` for the `UITextField` (specifying this either in IB or in code) and then implement a `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` that considers the length of the string:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldString = textField.text ?? ""
    let startIndex = oldString.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
    let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.length)
    let newString = oldString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(startIndex ..< endIndex, withString: string)
    return newString.characters.count <= kMaxLength
}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to control the amount of text entered to conform to the size of the control, you could use the aforementioned `shouldChangeTextInRange`, but use `sizeWithAttributes` to dictate whether that method returns true or false rather than the number of characters.

This isn't quite right, but it illustrates the basic idea:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldString = textField.text ?? ""
    let startIndex = oldString.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
    let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.length)
    let newString = oldString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(startIndex ..< endIndex, withString: string)
    let stringSize = newString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : textField.font ?? UIFont.systemFontSize()])

    return stringSize.width < textField.editingRectForBounds(textField.bounds).size.width
}
```

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated in Swift. sizeWithAttributes is the one looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and was working up example with `sizeWithAttributes`.

Answer (score 10):

You have to implement the `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

and then set the delegate of the textView in the viewDidLoad-method:

```
yourTextView.delegate = self
```

After that you can use the `shouldChangeTextInRange` method to check the letters:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
  let maxtext: Int = 140
  //If the text is larger than the maxtext, the return is false

  // Swift 2.0
  return textView.text.characters.count + (text.characters.count - range.length) <= maxtext

  // Swift 1.1
  // return countElements(textView.text) + (countElements(text.length) - range.length) <= maxtext 

}
```

The nice part in this solution is, that you can even control cut/copy and paste. So the user can't trick the field to accept more letters by copying.

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted it by mistake. It's simply the max amount of letters. I've added it.

Comment: I think that's not the right solution because you set a letter limit but if I change font and it has a different space between the letter hasn't the same size of before.

Comment: @Mala, _a_ letter is always only _one_ letter, does not matter which font you are using for the representation. if you are not looking for a limitation of the number of the characters, you may need to re-phrase your question.

Comment: First error:   `func textView(textview: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        var maxtext = 140;
        
        // String does not have a member named 'length'
        return textview.text.length + (text.length - range.length) <= maxtext
        
    } `  Second error:  `//Type ViewController does not conform to protocol UITExtViewDelegate   textview.delegate = self `     @c0dev

Comment: You have a typo in the UITextViewDelegate. Also instead of length you can use the function countElements(yourstring). I've edited my answer.

Comment: what kind of typo?   and now the second error is the same @c0dev

Comment: You Write UITExtViewDelegate but it has to be UITextViewDelegate. The E has to be lowercase.

Comment: that is the error, I've write that faster but the error is: type "ViewController" does not conform to protocol 'UITextViewDelegate'

Comment: How do you add the Delegate to the ViewController?

Comment: You have to add the UITextViewDelegate to your Class also:
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

Comment: This is much easier to understand than Rob's answer and much less code. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1) `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {`

2)  `textView.delegate = self`

3)

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let maxCharacter: Int = 1000
        return (textView.text?.utf16.count ?? 0) + text.utf16.count - range.length <= maxCharacter        
    }
```